# Does JS paho client has limited features compared to java client?

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt, paho

In browser side i am using `paho` client and server is `Activemq`. What i found is that paho JS client has very limited set of features but java client has lots of feature.

Some feature that i want is Message delivery confirmation, message time etc. how can i get all these kind of feature in browser side client or what should be a common architecture of MQTT chat applictaion  for these features. Shall i do separate Java api call for getting these kind of features ?

Comment: I believe you may be confusing the Paho MQTT clients (both Java and Javascript) and one of the other Java client libraries that will connect to ActiveMQ e.g. AMQP or STOMP

Comment: what i saw that paho java client has more feature then paho js client

Answer (score 0):

Both the [Java](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html#deliveryComplete(org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken)) and the [Javascript](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Client.html#onMessageDelivered) both have callbacks for onMessageDelivered

And MQTT has no fields for a timestamp, so I'm not sure where you've seen *Message Time*

Comment: in paho js client `onMessageDelivered` there are no way to know that message was received by other end user

Comment: i saw that `onMessageDelivered` is called for each message sent no matter if even a user received that

Comment: MQTT has no end to end delivery notification, the best you will get is confirmation the message has reached the broker with QOS 1/2 messages